# Laravel: Profile hasMany to other model

Tags: laravel-5.4

Partner ,
Agreement,
Collaboration

Partner hasMany Agreements
Agreements hasMany collaborations

Collaboration model has three fields are volunteers, grant_amount, hours and timestamps

I need to list all the partners and total no.of volunteers and total grant amount

Can you help me how to get the output?
**Partner Controller**

```
$partners = Partner::with(['currentYearDegree',
'agreements' => function($query){
 $query->select('id','partner_id','title')
 ->with(['collaborations']);
```

}])

```
foreach($partners as $partners )
{
 $partner->grant_amount = $partner->agreements->collaborations->sum('grant_amount')
}
```

It shows error message that "Call to undefined method collaborations"

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
foreach($partners as $partner )
    {
        $partner->grant_amount = 0;
        $partner->volunteers = 0;
        $partner->hours = 0;
        $partner->students = 0;
        foreach($partner->agreements as $agreement )
        {
            $partner->grant_amount += $agreement->collaborations->sum('grant_amount');
            $partner->volunteers += $agreement->collaborations->sum('volunteers');
            $partner->hours += $agreement->collaborations->sum('hours');
            $partner->students += $agreement->collaborations->sum('students');

        }

    }
```